Vim swap files not being created, when there is a $MYVIMRC file
I am using Vim 9.1
After installing Vim, swap files are created normally.
But if I create a $MYVIMRC file, Vim stops creating swap files.
If I put the line :set swapfile in the $MYVIMRC file, Vim still won't create swap files.
If I open a file and enter the command :set swapfile, edit the file, save and close it, Vim still won't create swap files.
If I remove the $MYVIMRC file, Vim creates swap files normally.
I was expecting Vim to keep creating swap files, even after I create the $MYVIMRC file.

Just to be clear, you didn't actually call that $MYVIMRC file $MYVIMRC, right? What is its real name and location?

You can use an .exrc file instead of a $MYVIMRC file.

The main difference between .exrc and .vimrc is that the latter will :set nocompatible. I couldn't find anything in :help 'compatible' that would suggest the swapfile or directory options would be affected by it. Please [edit] and clarify how this answer addresses OP's problem. Thank you.
